android name and application name probleme, android studio flutter
I am a programmer, but I am a beginner in the use of flutter.
i find a problem i can't solve.
I create the project it works, but the Android manifestxml page gives two errors ( android:name=“${applicationName}” and android:name=“.MainActivity”)
and in the mainActivity page it also gives, it seems that flutter can't read the embedded folder so if you open the android part of the project it works.
how can you help me please
androidxml page

Please do not provide code through images. Do it via highlights. Proper errors should also be included, not only "red highlights". Take a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
